# jQuery mouseclick counter - How to reset?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, click, reset

I am trying to make a site that counts each time the user has clicked their mouse. I have that part down, but I also need to include a reset button that, after the user clicks it, starts the mouse click counter back from 0.

I cannot figure it out - if I move the var = 0 about the doc ready, it resets, but after the button is clicked, the counter never goes past 1. I am not sure what to do.

My script -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log("Here");


    $(document).click(function(e) {
        $('#location').append("("+e.clientX+", "+e.clientY+")<br>");
    });

    var counter = 0;
    $(document).click(function(e) {
        counter++;
        $("#mouseclick").text("Total mouse clicks: " + counter);
    });

    $('button').click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();  // stop the event from propagating up the visual tree
        $('#location').text("");
        $("#mouseclick").text("Total mouse clicks: 0");
    });

    $('button')
});
```

I need them to be able to click 'button' and the count will reset. Any advice?

Comment: First counter = 0; then $("#mouseclick").text("Total mouse clicks: " + counter); =)

Comment: What is " $('button') " at the end?

Comment: In your button click event, simply set `counter=0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not resetting the counter. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7z5f3zbd/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log("Here");


$(document).click(function(e) {
  $('#location').append("("+e.clientX+", "+e.clientY+")<br>");
});

var counter = 0;
$(document).click(function(e) {
  counter++;
  $("#mouseclick").text("Total mouse clicks: " + counter);
});

$('button').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();  // stop the event from propagating up the visual tree
  $('#location').text("");
  counter = 0;
  $("#mouseclick").text("Total mouse clicks: 0");
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought I had done this last night, but in retrospect I had put var counter=0; rather than just counter=0;. 

Thank you!

Comment: Actually, if I can ask - why would var counter=0; not work, as opposed to counter=0;? Is it because the variable is already defined so it becomes redundant?

Comment: If you redefine a variable using the `var` keyword, it usually throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

Just add counter=0 in $('button').click() event.

```
$('button').click(function(e) {
   counter=0;
   e.stopPropagation();  // stop the event from propagating up the visual tree
   $('#location').text("");
   $("#mouseclick").text("Total mouse clicks: 0");
});
```

Comment: Oh my god.... That was so easy. I seriously thought I had tried everything. Totally overthinking this, haha. Thank you!!